# Почему наличие унарного плюса в нижеприведенном коде делает ее ошибочной?

Tags: javascript

```
(+(("lastIndexOf") in []) ** 55 + 2) + 5
```

Comment: Дело в приоритетах?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Во многих языках, таких как PHP и Python и других, есть оператор
>   возведения в степень (обычно `^` или `**`), оператор определён
>   имеющим приоритет выше, чем у унарных операторов, таких как унарный `+`
>   и унарный `-`, но есть несколько исключений. Например, в Bash оператор
>   `**` создан имеющим приоритет ниже, чем у унарных операторов. В JavaScript невозможно написать двухсмысленное выражение, т.е. вы не
>   можете ставить унарный оператор (`+/-/~/!/delete/void/typeof`) непосредственно перед базовым числом.

Взято [ОТСЮДА](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Другими словами: это ограничение js'а - нельзя использовать унарный оператор перед базовым числом (числом которое возводится в степень) из-за "двусмысленности".

**Варианты исправления.**

Явно указываем порядок действий:
`((+(("lastIndexOf") in [])) ** 55 + 2) + 5`

Используем старый метод:
`(Math.pow(+("lastIndexOf" in []), 55) + 2) + 5`

Comment: Любопытно, но [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) унарный плюс выше, чем возведение. Где путаница тогда?

Comment: @Other, действительно занятно, есть повод покопаться в этом неведомом и полурабочем es7 ...

Comment: @Other, все оказалось проще чем казалось, достаточно было лишь открыть английскую версию и увидеть слово "base", приоритет ни при чем, это просто ограничение (правда, с чем связано все равно осталось неясным).

Comment: @Other, вроде они там передумали, из-за чего решили вообще запретить. Но я думал, это только минуса касается.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Что передумали?